# Clearing flask session flash messages after pytest tests

Tags: flask

I have a Flask site that I'm testing using pytest. I want to test that some views are setting `flask.flash` messages correctly. I can do this, but the flash messages persist between tests and I'd like them to clear.

I have this `test_client` fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app():
    # create_app() returns a configured Flask app:
    app = create_app("testing")
    with app.test_request_context():
        yield app

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_client(app):
    with app.test_client() as c:
        yield c
```

And I have tests like this:

```py
from flask import session

def test_my_redirect_view(test_client):
    "It should redirect and set the correct flash message"
    response = test_client.get("/my/path", follow_redirects=False)

    assert response.status_code == 302
    assert response.location == "http://localhost/a/different/url"

    assert "_flashes" in session
    assert len(session["_flashes"]) == 1
    assert session["_flashes"][0][0] == "warning"
    assert session["_flashes"][0][1] == "My error message"
```

As I say, assuming my view sets this flash message, and redirects correctly, this test passes. But a subsequent, similar test, will fail because then `len(session["_flashes"])` will be `2`, because it has the messages from both tested views.

I've tried doing this at the end of each test, but with no apparent effect:

```py
    del session["_flashes"][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal answer, because it doesn't ensure the tested view only sets a single flash message, but for now I'm replacing the `assert` lines related to the flash messages with:

```py
    assert ("warning", "My error message") in session["_flashes"]
```